# regex matching components of string and repositioning

Tags: regex, sed

I have a number of strings that I would like to search and reformat in [a file](https://gist.github.com/equilet/5f9358898bfaf4dd3a357e5dbd727686).  I'm using gsed v4.7 on MacOS 10.14.6 to do this.  My goal is to break the strings up into backreferences so that I can then reformat.

**Here is a single example of a candidate being transformed:**

`vib.h.p.a#3.synt 8`

would become

`vib.h.p.a#3.8.synt`

...note that the number `8` is removed from the end and spliced between `#3` and `synt`, separated by dots.

**Here is a list of candidates:**

```
vib.h.p.f2.synt 4
vib.h.p.g#2.synt 7
vib.h.p.a#3.synt 8
```

If you look at the components of this exemplary string, they can be broken down into groups fairly easily.

I cannot find a way to formalize this into an expression that matches the needs of `gsed`.

**Here is what I have tried:**

`gsed -r 's/(vib\.+)\.(.+)\s(\d)/\1.\3.\2/g' myfile.txt`

`gsed -r 's/vib\.(.*)\.(.*)\s(\d)/vib.\1\3\2/g' myfile.txt`

`gsed -r 's/(vib\..*)\.(.*)\s(\d)/\1.\3.\2/g' myfile.txt`

I know that I'm missing something critical, possibly a way to lookahead negatively?
My intuition tells me that I am close to a solution, although I've given up for the night.

**EDIT 12/16/19** - The answer below by @Wiktor suggested a command like

`gsed -r 's/(vib.+)\.(.+)[[:blank:]]+([0-9]+)/\1.\3.\2/g' myfile.txt`

This does not print the desired transformation on my machine.  Instead, it prints the original text without any substitutions, as it is not matching successfully. I am unable to test on another machine, so I do not know if this is the correct answer, but I have tried all variants suggested, including using `[[:space:]]`, `[[:blank:]]`, `[0-9]`, and `+` instead of `*`.  If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share the version of gsed ? Please expand on 'This does not perform the desired ...' - what is the output that you get ?

Comment: The attempts that you listed do not include quotes - How do you run them ?

Comment: @dash-o - amended with the info you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

`([.#0-9a-zA-Z]+\.)(\S*)\s+([0-9]+)`

and replace with `$1$3.$2`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YccNOj/4)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
gsed -r 's/(vib.+)\.(.+)[[:blank:]]+([0-9]+)/\1.\3.\2/g' myfile.txt
```

The main points:

- `\.+` matches one or more dots, not any one or more chars, hence you need to remove the backslash
- `\d` and `\s` are not quite portable and thus it makes sense to replace `\d` with `[0-9]` and  `\s` with a space or `[[:blank:]]`
- If there are more digits than one in Group 3, you may end up with a part of a number being swapped, add `+` (since you use `-r` option the POSIX ERE syntax will treat `+` as a *one or more occurrences* quantifier).

Comment: Thanks, although it does not seem to work.  Using `gsed` v4.7 on OSX 10.14.6 (18G1012)

Comment: @jml Note that the s command should be in single quotes. On OSX, you may just use `sed -E 's/(vib.+)\.(.+)[[:blank:]]+([0-9]+)/\1.\3.\2/g' myfile.txt`

Comment: Yes, I included the single quotes.  Neither `-E` nor `-r` options work with `gsed` or `sed` here.  I also tried variants that included `\s`, `\d`, and `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: @jml What do you mean by "work"? Do you pipe the result to a file? Or do you use the `-i` flag to save the results in the file? `sed -E 's/(vib.+)\.(.+)[[:blank:]]+([0-9]+)/\1.\3.\2/g' myfile.txt > output.txt`. See the [demo of the sed command](https://ideone.com/oRrsZC).

Comment: `-r` or `-E` is just printing to std output, and the result is unchanged, so the text replacement is not functioning.  I tried piping to a file and get the same (undesired) result.

Comment: @jml Since the overall idea is correct, you may explore the following: 1) replace `[[:blank:]]` with a space or `[ ]`, 2) try a POSIX BRE variant with some simplified patterns: `sed 's/\(vib.*\)\.\(.*\)[ ][ ]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\1.\3.\2/g' myfile.txt`

Comment: will do and report back!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204364/discussion-between-jml-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found something that does the replacement I was hoping for.

`gsed -r 's/(vib.\w.)(\w+.(\w[0-9]|\w\#[0-9]).)(\w+)\s([0-9])/\1\2\5.\4/g' myfile.txt`

This works for my needs, but there is probably a be a far more elegant way.
I'm including the text I used as a test [here](https://gist.github.com/equilet/5f9358898bfaf4dd3a357e5dbd727686), in the event that someone can figure out what a better solution would be.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simple one to me. What am I missing?

```
echo "vib.h.p.f2.synt 4" | sed -E 's/(.*[0-9]+)(\.[^0-9]+) ([0-9]+)$/\1.\3\2/g'
vib.h.p.f2.4.synt
```

Note that this was done with stock sed in macOS, where `-E` gets you ERE.

Note also that this *could* be done using character classes, like this:

```
... sed -E 's/(.*[[:digit:]]+)(\.[^[:digit:]]+) ([[:digit:]]+)$/\1.\3\2/g'
```

But if you need to use character classes, you probably already know that. :)

Comment: this does not cover all cases enumerated in the file listed above (see question)

Comment: @jml, can you be more specific? The OP provided a **single example**, and this solution works for that example. As I asked, what am I missing?